# Component created through Anguilla Framework is blocked

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme, gui-extensions

Anybody knows what is the reason because a Component created through Anguilla Framework (with clone code) is blocked until I refresh the CME? 
This is my code:

```
var componentCloned = $tcm.getItem("tcm:XX-XXXX").clone("tcm:XX-XXXX-2", "ComponentName", false);

$evt.addEventHandler(componentCloned, "loadfailed", function(event){
    alert(event.data.Message);
});

$evt.addEventHandler(componentCloned, "idchange", function(event){
    var controls = $display.getView().properties.controls;
    var tab = controls.TabControl.getSelectedItem();
    var list = tab.getListComponentPresentations();
    var cp = list.getItems();
    list.insertItems(cp.length, [event.source.getId()], "tcm:XX-XXXX-32");

    Save$execute$removeItemEventHandlers();
});
```

Then, when I try to open the Component, it always show me the message "Loading...":

[image]

In the folder I can see that the Component has been created correctly and it is not blocked or checked in.
Anybody knows what is the problem or any solution?

Comment: What does it say in console or performance tab ?

Comment: It says nothing Andrew, and I need to refresh the CME with CTRL+R to open it.

Comment: Anybody knows the reason?